# Why some row border has spacing in flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've designed a table with flexbox and the borders on alternate/every third row has a single pixel space between content.
[image: SS here]I couldn't find the space from the dev tools.
Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/z6fk8xo3/3/).

I've tried with 0 font size, changes in position and display property with no luck.
But when I set background color for the whole row, instead of one column, it fits well for all rows.

Like this,

```
.block {
    display: flex;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    .label {
      background-color: blue;
      padding: 10px;
      flex: 1;
    }
    .value {
      flex: 1;
    }
  }
```

Can someone help me find out where this extra space between border and content comes from and how to remove that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the question here ? I see table having proper design.

Comment: @abhinav3414 he is talking about the white space!! after label div

Comment: Is it about the extra space label div takes on right side, the space between label and value in each row ? Can you add an image about your exact issue. I don't see 1 px issue yet.

Comment: I don't understand what is the issue. The code work perfect.

Comment: @GermanoPlebani I've attached screensnap for the issue. You can see a space between border and content in rows 2 and 4, like a padding. I'm trying to remove that space.

Comment: @Ms.Tamil i don't see it on my iMac.

Comment: @GermanoPlebani oh, Not sure how that works. But in windows it shows like above.

Comment: Can you add your markup (HTML text) as well? It's important. If you use the `table` element, for instance, there is a number of default CSS rules that apply, one of which adds a border around table cells which is why your table looks like it does.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change all border to .5px
and no need to ad a border with the last .bloc

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works! Can you please add an explanation how it works.

Comment: in fact the one before had no error, but the browser like chrome adds a margin without expressing itself, you can test the old version with firefox 

Comment: and .block: not (: last-child) it's just to select the first 4 .block so as not to have a double border at the last

Comment: Thanks, Even if I add 0 margin, its showing the gap. But for 1.5px there is no gap. Can I please get more information regarding this behavior somewhere.

Comment: this is a problem that I have not found a concrete explanation until now 

Answer (score 0):

This has mostly to do with subpixel rendering on a zoomed in Chrome browsers. A lot of windows laptops have their display settings default at 150%, so it renders a 1px line at 1.5px.
Firefox is obviously better at this then Chrome, by the way. But this explains why some people using chrome do see the issue, and some don't. To reproduce, zoom in on Chrome on a site with small borders.

Chen Hui Jing has some good explanations on subpixel rendering on different browsers -> [Sub-pixel rendering and borders](https://chenhuijing.com/blog/about-subpixel-rendering-in-browsers/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).